# Output not printed to screen when command chain is executed from Groovy Script

Tags: bash, groovy

I wrote the following Groovy code:

```
#!/opt/groovy-2.4.12/bin/groovy
String todayDate = new Date().format( 'yy-MM-dd' )
def p = ['/usr/bin/aws', 'rds', 'describe-db-snapshots', '--db-instance-identifier dev-rds-2017-10-02', '--snapshot-type automated', '--query "DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>=' + todayDate +'.DBSnapshotIdentifier"'].execute() | 'grep rds'.execute() | ['tr', '-d', '\'\"|[:space:]\''].execute()
p.waitFor()
//p.waitFor()
println todayDate
println p.text
```

Which is supposed to return the name of the latest RDS snapshot id.

When I run the script in terminal, the only output that I get is the `println todayDate` but not the output of the aws cli command.

**Edit #1:**

This is the output of the command when I run it in terminal:

```
$ /usr/bin/aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier dev-rds-2017-10-02 --snapshot-type automated --query "DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>='$todaydate'].DBSnapshotIdentifier" | grep rds | tr -d '\"'
    rds:dev-rds-2017-10-02-2017-11-22-00-05
```

**Edit #2:**

```
[jenkins@ip-X-X-X-X ~]$ /usr/bin/aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier dev-rds-2017-10-02 --snapshot-type automated --query "DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>='2017-11-23'].DBSnapshotIdentifier" | grep rds | tr -d '\"'
    rds:dev-rds-2017-10-02-2017-11-23-00-05
[jenkins@ip-X-X-X-X ~]$ groovy -d rdssnapshotid.groovy
/usr/bin/aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier dev-rds-2017-10-02 --snapshot-type automated --query "DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>='2017-11-23'].DBSnapshotIdentifier" | grep rds | tr -d '\"'

[jenkins@ip-X-X-X-X ~]$
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Cause I get no errors...

Comment: Are you sure the command is correct? can you check for the errors to see what is going on?

Comment: Please check my Edit #1, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it incorrectly.

Just see if the statement generate the right command first. But it does not.

Here is the fixed script which generates the expected command. Later you can execute it.

```
def todaydate = new Date().format( 'yy-MM-dd' )
def cmd = ['/usr/bin/aws', 'rds', 'describe-db-snapshots', '--db-instance-identifier', 'dev-rds-2017-10-02', '--snapshot-type', 'automated', '--query', "\"DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>='${todaydate}'].DBSnapshotIdentifier\"", '|', 'grep', 'rds', '|', 'tr', '-d', "'\\\"'"]
println cmd.join(' ')
```

Here is online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/myB87g)</kbd> for quick try.

You may want to execute it? Then do

```
def process = cmd.execute()
process.waitFor()
println process.text
```

**EDIT:** Based on the comments (to address the pipe issue, though generated command is ok)

```
def todaydate = new Date().format( 'yy-MM-dd' )
def process = ['/usr/bin/aws', 'rds', 'describe-db-snapshots', '--db-instance-identifier', 'dev-rds-2017-10-02', '--snapshot-type', 'automated', '--query', "\"DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>='${todaydate}'].DBSnapshotIdentifier\""].execute() | ['grep', 'rds'].execute() | ['tr', '-d', "'\\\"'"].execute()
process.waitFor()
println process.text
```

Comment: Have you tried that or something similar to execute?  The `|` there will not do what OPs expecting. Granted OP could do the `grep|tr` as well with groovy instead.  Also _not_ joining for the execute is far more safe, because you are not at the mercy of groovy splitting things on `<space>`.

Comment: @Rao, please check my Edit #2, output is still empty when ran from the groovy script.

Comment: @ItaiGanot, appreciate first if you can confirm that whether the script is generating the command right?

Comment: @ItaiGanot, thank you for the confirmation. And what happens when you manually take the generated command and execute it in the terminal? Does it yield expected outcome?

Comment: Yes, when I run the generated command in shell it returns the expected output.

Comment: @ItaiGanot, thank you for your patience. Just edited the answer, look after `EDIT` part to see if that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159673/discussion-between-itai-ganot-and-rao).

Comment: Still getting an empty output even when commenting out the second pipe.

Comment: Can you please delete your answer so other users will be able to try? thanks

Comment: Not sure what exactly the issue is, you have not shown up in the chat request which you have initiated. By the way, you are not new to SO site right? A question can have any number of answers.